# trying to put the bootstrap-datepicker in my rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
I am trying to put the datepicker in my rails project.
Here the date is not pop up. I follow the instruction use javascripts n all but it does not pop up the date selector.

It is for my application.js file

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
    $('#dp5').datepicker()
```

for my view file

```
<div class="well">
<div id="dp5" class="input-append date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-02-2012">
<input class="span2" type="dp5" readonly="" value="12-02-2012" size="16">
<span class="add-on">
<i class="icon-th"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Need source code with *.js files.

Comment: Works for me, even with the sub-standard `type="dp5"`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/Jndyq/). Are you seeing any errors in your console? Is the **application.js** definitely being loaded after the **bootstrap-datepicker.js**?

Answer (score 1):

Add in application.js

```
//= require_self
```

and add `$('#dp5').datepicker()` when dom loaded

```
$(function() {
   $('#dp5').datepicker()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call the datepicker on on a `type` HTML element when it should be called on a class or id. Try changing:

```
<input class="span2" type="dp5" readonly="" value="12-02-2012" size="16">
```

To:

```
<input class="span2" id="dp5" readonly="" value="12-02-2012" size="16">
```

And it should work.

Comment: -1 Even though the `type="dp5"` is substandard, it's not the issue. He's initializing the datepicker plugin on the `<div>` which contains the input, which is following the conventions of the documentation.

Comment: I totally missed the `id` attribute on the div as I am used to using standard JQueryUI datepicker which is initialized on a text field.