# Twitter bootstrap datepicker is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I download the bootstrap-datepicker.js and include it in my application .js file.
It is not working in view

```
 <div class="well">
<div id="dp5" class="input-append date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-02-2012">
<input class="span2" type="dp5" readonly="" value="12-02-2012" size="16">
<span class="add-on">
<i class="icon-th"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

It is not displaying the calender for date. where m i wrong?

my application.js file is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker

//= require picker
//= require_tree .

$('#dp5').datepicker()
```

Comment: any firebug errors? is bootsrapt-datepicker.js getting properly included?

Comment: no firebug errors . if you use date picker earlier in rails then please give me suggestion what u did .

Comment: -1 for double posting the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12072689/570918

Comment: @merv sorry for double posting. If u have any idea then u can share answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `//= require_self` to application.js

this includes its own file contents too.
This has to be done explicitly.

also keep the application.js  formatted

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require picker
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

$(function() {
   $('#dp5').datepicker()
 });

// Do not keep bank spaces between included files.
```

I would suggest to create a new js file and add contents in it and then include it in application.js

keep application.js as a index file

Comment: its my own js just m namin it picker it is for select all check box js. n working fine in my app

Comment: aaahhh I got it, check updated answer, apply the datapicker when dom loads

Comment: my form has the format like                                     <%= f.radio_button :status, 2 %>Trash  How can i bring date picker in this formate in my form? <%= f.   %>  ?

Comment: Now the datepicker works successfully. Now i want to use it in my form in rails . which have formate like <div class="form-inputs">        <%= f.input :Projects %> <%= f.date (datepicker)%></div>  How can i do that such that value of date come in date?

Comment: @regmiprem, I would ask you to open a new question to this, too much things in one question may confuse another users.

Comment: ok. I already opened    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087794/how-can-i-put-the-bootstrap-datepicker-in-my-form-and-have-the-value-in-date-par