# How can i put the bootstrap datepicker in my form and have the value in date parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-datepicker.js and it is working fine.

```
<div class="well">
<div id="dp5" class="input-append date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-02-2012">
<input class="span2" type="dp5" readonly="" value="12-02-2012" size="16">
<span class="add-on">
<i class="icon-th"></i>
</span>
</div>

  </div>
```

I want to use it in my form in rails which is of such type

```
<%= simple_form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :address %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :Projects %>
     <%= f.radio_button :status, 0, :checked => true%>Publish
    <%= f.radio_button :status, 1 %>Unpublish
    <%= f.radio_button :status, 2 %>Trash


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here i want to put the date picker inside my form as

```
`<%f.(datepicker)%>`
```

so that when i submit my form i get the value of date in the parameter date. When i click on date in datepicker it should hide and the default date should point to the current date. my appication.js includes

```
 $(function(){  
        $('#dp5').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });
        $('#dp3').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<%= f.text_field :name_of_the_date_column, :value=>Date.today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), :id =>"dp5" %>`

To auto hide use this

```
$("#dt5").datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    })
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
  $('#dt5').datepicker('hide');
});
```

instead of

```
$("#dt5").datepicker();
```

Comment: Ya it works hide process but date starts from 19... I want to be active initially in the present date and after clickin date when we want to edit it again it doesnt work.

Comment: Ya it gives current date in the text field but clickin datepicker starts from 1982 when it clicked.

Comment: this is wierd its working for me, you sure you have applied it to correct element?

Comment: ya i mean to say all is working fine beside the date picker activates in 1982 when click.

Comment: I guess some where you might have javascript that is applying the date to the input

Comment: all if you are using the same datepicker config instead of applying it to all individual ids apply it to a class and use that in all places

Answer (score 5):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19018373/2238268) and have included my answer below:

---

I also needed to get this working and support multiple locales that do not use US centric date formats, eg: en-AU (Australia) which has the date format dd/mm/yyyy.

## The Problem

Rails expects the date format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` from the browser, yet you want to display the date in the user's locale.  Whilst the date control allows you to specify the format for display it does NOT allow you to separately specify the format to be sent back to the server.

## The Solution

Build a hidden input field that sends the correct format back to your rails server.  I do this with with a custom simple_form input control that builds both the date-picker input field and a hidden field, and use some javascript to convert to the rails date when the input control changes.

The upshot is you can have a nice bootstrap date-picker in rails and use it with simple_form as follows:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker %>
```

Or to use a long date format:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker, input_html: { format: :long } %>
```

## Implementation

Create or edit the following files:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**config/locales/en-AU.yml**

```
en-AU:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: "dd MM, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
      long: ! '%d %B, %Y'
```

**config/locales/en-US.yml**

```
en-US:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "mm/dd/yyyy"
      long: "MM dd, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: ! '%B %d, %Y'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
#= require bootstrap
#= require bootstrap-datepicker
#= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

Alternatively, **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

**app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  # convert bootstrap-datepicker value to rails date format (yyyy-mm-dd) on our hidden field
  $(document).on 'changeDate', '.bootstrap-datepicker', (evt) ->
    rails_date = evt.date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (evt.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + evt.date.getDate()).slice(-2)
    $(this).next("input[type=hidden]").val(rails_date)
```

**app/inputs/bootstrap_datepicker_input.rb**

```
class BootstrapDatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    text_field_options = input_html_options.with_indifferent_access
    format =  text_field_options.delete(:format)
    hidden_field_options = text_field_options.dup
    hidden_field_options[:class] = text_field_options[:class].dup # so they won't work with same array object
    hidden_field_options[:id] = "#{attribute_name}_hidden"
    text_field_options[:class] << 'bootstrap-datepicker'
    text_field_options[:type] = 'text'
    text_field_options[:value] ||= format_date(value(object), format)
    set_data_option text_field_options, 'date-format', I18n.t(format, scope: [:date, :datepicker], default: :default)
    default_data_option text_field_options, 'provide', 'datepicker'

    return_string =
      "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, text_field_options.to_hash)}\n" +
      "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, hidden_field_options.to_hash)}\n"
    return return_string.html_safe
  end

protected

  def default_data_option(hash, key, value)
    set_data_option(hash,key,value) unless data_option(hash, key)
  end

  def data_option(hash, key)
    hash[:data].try(:[],key) || hash["data-#{key}"]
  end

  def set_data_option(hash, key, value)
    hash[:data].try(:[]=,key,value) || (hash["data-#{key}"] = value)
  end

  def value(object)
    object.send @attribute_name if object
  end

  def format_date(value, format=nil)
    value.try(:strftime, I18n.t(format, scope: [ :date, :formats ], default: :default))
  end
end
```

Comment: For the en-US default date format, it should probably be '%m/%d/%Y' instead of 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Answer (score 3):

You can express this more concisely:

```
$("#dt5").datepicker({
                           format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                           autoclose: true
                           })
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked all the answers, none worked for me. I have used the following:

```
<%= f.text_field :article_date, {"data-provide" => 'datepicker', 
                                 "data-date-format" => "yyyy-mm-dd"} %>
```

In my case, MySQL expected `yyyy-mm-dd` format, while datepicker default format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. IMHO, users do not care about format, so I would rather have the same format all over the place and save myself a lot of trouble.